# Mounting webdav shares using davfs2

Tags: linux, sharepoint, webdav, mount

I am trying to mount a SharePoint directory (located on a Windows server) on my Ubuntu machine using davfs2. I get the "Secure connection truncated" error. Following is what I do and the output (with some omissions):

```
$ sudo mount -t davfs 'https://<server_url>' /mnt/<mount_directory>/
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
  Username: <username>
Please enter the password to authenticate user <username> with server
  Password: <password>
/sbin/mount.davfs: the server certificate is not trusted
  issuer:      <issuer>
  subject:     <subject>
  identity:    <identity>
  fingerprint: <fingerprint>
You only should accept this certificate, if you can
verify the fingerprint! The server might be faked
or there might be a man-in-the-middle-attack.
Accept certificate for this session? [y,N] y
/sbin/mount.davfs: Mounting failed.
Could not read status line: Secure connection truncated
```

Has anyone got an idea what may cause this problem and how to solve it? Will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: can anyone help us fix this? I am getting same error too..!

Comment: @Dharmavir maybe then it is a good idea to vote it up, maybe that helps making it more visible.

Comment: Did my bit of it. Were you able to find solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks. No I didn't, I just gave up :)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the `-o_netdev` option to the mount command. This fixed the "Secure connection truncated" error for me, most of the times. ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look into my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043417/mounting-a-sharepoint-filesystem-on-linux-using-davfs2

It might help you.